# knockout "if binding" not working

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

When debugging with Chrome, I can see CoverPrices has 9 elements. The foreach loop actually works well and the table looks correct with the first span being bound to Item1 correctly.

However, the if binding does not work and both images are displayed. Yet, all the elements in Item2 have the true value, so only the first image should show up.

```
<!-- ko foreach: CoverPrices -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: Item1"></span>
        </td>
        <!-- ko foreach: Item2 -->
        <td>
            <img src="~/Images/yes.png" alt="oui" data-bind="if: $data" /> 
            <img src="~/Images/no.png" alt="non" data-bind="ifnot: $data" /> 
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Is there something wrong with my binding ?

Comment: Can you post how is your `Item2` collection look like?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `if-binding` does not affect the whole element, but its *content*. And because an `img` element does not have content, the binding does not matter.

This will work, with `span`  as container elements:

```html
<span data-bind="if: $data"><img src="~/Images/yes.png" alt="oui" /></span>
<span data-bind="ifnot: $data"><img src="~/Images/no.png" alt="non" /></span>
```

There is also a [container-less syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), if you don't want the additional elements:

```html
<!-- ko if: $data -->
    <img src="~/Images/yes.png" alt="oui" />
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: $data -->
    <img src="~/Images/no.png" alt="non" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Or use the visible binding instead?

Comment: @PaulManzotti valid point, in this code there is no reason to use "if" because there are no other bindings involved.

Comment: @fab thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. I ended up using visible binding as it seems more appropriate in this case indeed

Comment: Nice, this one had me scratching my head for a few minutes.

Comment: Not the element but its content... 2 hours of my life I'll never get back!

Answer (score 0):

Image is not binding to DOM, but the image is loading. You can check in Network traffic. It should not load when if bind is used