# Knockout.js - Display image base on table values

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table with 9 columns. What I want to be able to do, using knockoutjs, is to display 1 of three images depending upon if certain columns are null. The code bellow shows my latest atempt, however it places all 3 images in the cell as if everything where returning true.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:xrefs">
    <tr>

        <td>


            @*<img data-bind="if: API14 == null || PROP_NM == null || PROD_ZONE_NM == null || LEASE_NAME == null || WELL_NO == null" src="~/img/warning_25.png" />
            <img data-bind="if: PROP_NO == null || ENTITY == null" src="~/img/error-25.png"/>
            <img data-bind="ifnot: PROP_NO == null || ENTITY == null || API14 == null || PROP_NM == null || PROD_ZONE_NM == null || LEASE_NAME == null || WELL_NO == null " src="~/img/green_Chk_25.png" />*@
        </td>



        <td data-bind="text:API14"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:PROP_NO"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:PROP_NM"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:ENTITY"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:PROD_ZONE_NM"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:LEASE_NAME"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:WELL_NO"></td>
        <td class="text-nowrap">
            <a data-bind="attr:{href:'@Url.Action("Details")/'+id}" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
            <a data-bind="attr:{href:'@Url.Action("Edit")/'+id}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <a data-bind="attr:{href:'@Url.Action("Delete")/'+id}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knockout "if binding" not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382788/knockout-if-binding-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if binding only shows/hides the **content** of the element that the binding is applied to. To get your IMG elements to disappear you'll have to wrap each one in a containing element, or use the knockout virtual element, for the binding.

```
<td>      
    <!-- ko if: API14 == null || PROP_NM == null || PROD_ZONE_NM == null || LEASE_NAME == null || WELL_NO == null -->
        <img src="~/img/warning_25.png" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    ...
</td>
```